# Read file and store into array

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to read the file and get file content and store it in 2 element array [0]: is for content [1]: is for NULL value. This code is working correctly when just I want to print it but I want to use as an array:

```
char ch;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("input.txt","r");

    int allocated_size = 10;
    int used_size = 0;
    char c, *input, *tmp_input;

  // allocate our buffer
  input = (char*)malloc(allocated_size);
  if (input == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation error");
    return 1;
  }

  while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){

    // make sure there's an empty one at the end to avoid
    // having to do this check after the loop
    if (used_size == allocated_size-1) {

      allocated_size *= 2;
      tmp_input = (char*)realloc(input, allocated_size);
      if (tmp_input == NULL) {
        free (input);
        printf("Memory allocation error");
        return 1;
      }
      input = tmp_input;
    }

    input[used_size++] = c;
  }

  // we are sure that there's a spot for last one
  // because of if (used_size == allocated_size-1)
  input[used_size] = '\0';

  printf("\nEntered string in the file: %s\n", input);
```

But how can I use "input" like an array:

```
char *input[] = {"This is string value from file!", NULL};
```

For this case I can get access to the text in this way: `input[0]`

Comment: `because of if (used_size == allocated_size-1)` wrong. The used_size varable has already been incremented when you fall out of the loop. (add an assert(), and you'll see it. once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to achieve this

```
    char *input[] = {"This is string value from file!", NULL};
```

If I am understanding correctly from your write-up then declare input as this

```
    char *input[2];
```

And every time you perform any operation on your string pointer e.g. malloc and re-alloc etc. use input[0] . This way array's first record will contain your text.

The reason behind this, the string in first record means you need array of char pointers.